# Conditional types in flow

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Is it possible to type a variable in flow based on a condition? Something like this:

```
const type = 'xyz';
const a: (type === 'xyz') ? number : string;
```

Comment: No it isn't. And this is a very strange requirement. What are you hoping to be able to achieve with that?

Comment: I have two rather complex types. Based on some function parameter, a variable is either the one or the other. But I guess I can use just the Union of both instead.

Comment: If you're using an object to group these variables together, you could look at [disjoint union types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/#toc-disjoint-unions).

Comment: @PeterHall not strange at all. TypeScript found good reason to implement this. It's a very useful construct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is no. A variable must be bound to a single type, which can include a union type like `number | string`. Inside a conditional block Flow can infer a more specialised type. For example:

```
const a: number | string = "foo";
if(typeof a === "string"){
  a.split(); // OK!
} else {
  a.split(); // Error! a is a number
}
```

But notice that these conditional branches are static, and it's guaranteed at compile time what the type will be inside each.

Answer (score 22):

Type-level conditions in Flow may be simulated using type calls (`$Call` type):

```
type $If<X: boolean, Then, Else = empty> = $Call<
    & ((true, Then, Else) => Then)
    & ((false, Then, Else) => Else),
    X,
    Then,
    Else,
>;

type $Not<X: boolean> = $If<X, false, true>;
type $And<X: boolean, Y: boolean> = $If<X, Y, false>;
type $Or<X: boolean, Y: boolean> = $If<X, true, Y>;

type $Gte<X, Y> = $Call<
    & ($Subtype<X> => true)
    & (mixed => false),
    Y,
>;

// Usage example:

declare var a: $Gte<number, string>;

/* error  1 */ (a: true);
/* ok       */ (a: false);

declare var b: $Gte<number, number>;

/* ok       */ (b: true);
/* error  2 */ (b: false);

declare var c: $If<true, 1, 2>;

/* ok       */ (c: 1);
/* error  3 */ (c: 2);

declare var d: $If<false, 1, 2>;

/* error  4 */ (d: 1);
/* ok       */ (d: 2);
```

More usage examples may be found in [gist](https://gist.github.com/miyaokamarina/934887ac2aff863b9c73283acfb71cf0).