# How to constrain a type based on another type with flow?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Imagine I have a flow type like this.

```
type Sample = {
    someProp: "foo" | "bar";
    arr: Array<string | number>
}
```

The idea is that I would like to enforce the type of array based on the string value used for `someProp`. In other words, if say the type of `someProp` is "foo" I want the type of `arr` to be `Array<string>`, but if the type of `someProp` is "bar", I want the type of `arr` to be `Array<number>`.

I understand that my example's approach may be off, so I guess I am asking how I would do this at all. I was thinking about using generics somehow, but I just don't understand how to go about this at all.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44823652/conditional-types-in-flow) help?

Answer (score 2):

using `$Call` utility type (https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-call) you can constrain this relatively easily. It gets harder when you want to further genericize this but if you can use string literal values in your types then you should be ok

```
type Sample<T: "foo" | "bar"> = {
    someProp: T,
    arr: Array<Constrained<T>>
}

type Constrained<T: string> = $Call<("foo" => string) & ("bar" => number), T>

let x: Sample<"foo"> = {
  someProp: "foo",
  arr: ["hello", "no numbers", "here", 2]
}

let y: Sample<"bar"> = {
  someProp: "bar",
  arr: [1, 2, 3, "oops"]
}
```

[Try Link](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAyghgWzAGwgHgCoC4oCIBmA9oblAD54BGcATrgHxQC8UA3gFBRdQDOhCEAAo1CYHBgA0nbrRo4AgjRpwQaAMKEAdj2DKAlpogATTPXrsAvu3ahIUDdt1wDxzDh00DAc0YsAJGpwyMhoABQExKRMjB7eAJRQAGRQ4dR0zIyaAK4IlBA0cRJQGOZc7KjAUAAeOPBIqGgRJL5s0nwCwqI4TbhSXLI4ANq4ABYQwSRFuJqEUNm5+Ty9eGM0EMsATAC6ltYVUCC1iCjouGkMzK1c7UIiYlS0vdIDUIMAjEUbRQDMU8RgSx2FiAA0)