# Why imported type goes error while the exact same type in local file goes fine in Flow function intersection

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Edit: [I reported an issue on facebook/flow.](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/7504)

---

Please let me ask a question here though it's about very specific case in Facebook Flow Types.

I wrote a bit complicated type for a class `Hole`. It's `.pipe()` function accepts an argument of not only `T => U` but `T => Promise<U>` and both always returns `Hole<U>`.

In the `T => Promise<U>` case, it looks working fine as you can see with `LocalType` in the below example. However, when I use the exact same type imported from the other file, the function intersection ([someone calls it Flow Conditional Types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49912339/804314)) fails to find the correct match in the list.

I'm totally lost in whether it's a bug of Flow Types or my misunderstanding of how function intersection works. I couldn't make the example more specific. I'd like to get any kind of clue about this so I'm glad if you respond. Thank you.

```js
// main.js
// @flow

import type {ExportedType} from './types';
type LocalType = number;

function useExported(e): Promise<ExportedType> {
  return (null: any);
}
function useLocal(e): Promise<LocalType> {
  return (null: any);
}
class Hole<T> {
  pipe<U, V>(fn: U): $Call<
      & ((T => Promise<?V>) => Hole<V>)
      & ((T => ?V) => Hole<V>),
      U> {
    return (null: any);
  }
}
function fromArray<T>(a: Array<T>): Hole<T> {
  return (null: any);
}

// Pass
(1: ExportedType);

// Pass
(1: LocalType);

// Pass
fromArray([1])
    .pipe(useLocal)
    .pipe(e => e);

// Error: ExportedType [1] is incompatible with Promise [2] in the return value.
fromArray([1])
    .pipe(useExported)
    .pipe(e => e);
```

```js
// ./types.js
// @flow

export type ExportedType = number;
```

The output

```
Error ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈ main.js:34:16

number [1] is incompatible with Promise [2] in the return value.

 [1]  6│ function useExported(e): Promise<ExportedType> {
       :
 [2] 15│       & ((T => Promise<?V>) => Hole<V>)
       :
     31│ // Error: ExportedType [1] is incompatible with Promise [2] in the return value.
     32│ fromArray([1])
     33│     .pipe(useExported)
     34│     .pipe(e => e);
     35│
     36│



Found 1 error
```

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation looks unnecessarily complicated. Try

```js
class Hole<T> {
  pipe<U>(fn: (T => Promise<?U>) | (T => ?U)): Hole<U> {
    return (null: any);
  }
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate you take your time. First, your function union type caused an error of message with `Could not decide which case to select. Since case 1 [1] may work but if it doesn't case 2 [2] looks promising too` in `.pipe(e => e)` (https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQjIFcB2BjALgS1uqAA4BOsAtrgM4CmAcquQEY0kAUNAlAFygAKZSrQA86RixIA+UAG9EoUCRrZUJQmzHRovAIboAnpwDciAL7JM0HVSqgAErGg1hAFWlyFRXEWcBVSWyQ6Lxs8grhAD6gbC6gALzSAhTUzgD8-pxh4aBRMfHS6ZkKnDz2jn7uWYrKquqa2qB6hiYK5uYoGDj4hJCCAIIkJDr6rgE6vANDI26lDk6jsmFKKmrR9boGxmbIIPzWVCj9g8NsANoAjAC6ReEAdF4+bKTJtAzMrDcK9940HPmL2QUHF4YneJC22VMW0QQA).

Comment: Second I tried function **intersection** type similar to you way but it also didn't work because it returns `Hole<Promise<U>>` instead of extracting `U` and returning `Hole<U>` which I expected. (https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQjIFcB2BjALgS1uqAA4BOsAtrgM4CmAcquQEY0kAUNAlAFygAKZSrQA86RixIA+UAG9EoUCRrZUJQmzHRovAIboAnpwDciAL7JM0HVSqgAErGg1hAFWlyFRXEWcBVSWyQ6Lxs8grhAGSgbC6gALzSAhTUzgD8-pxh4aBRMfHS6ZkKnDz2jn7uWYrKquqa2qB6hiYK5uYoGDj4hJCCAIIkJDr6rgE6vANDI26lDk6jsmFKKmrR9boGxmbIIPzWVCj9g8NsANoAjAC6ReEAdF4+bKTJtAzMrDcK9940HPmL2QUHF4YneJC22VMW0QQA)

Comment: I assume that your `(e: number)` was an attempt to satisfy the error's `To fix add a type annotation to return [3]`. Provide an annotated identity function to satisfy this error, e.g. https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQjIFcB2BjALgS1uqAA4BOsAtrgM4CmAcquQEY0kAUNAXKOoyyQEpuABTKVaAHl7NWAPlABvRKFAka2VCUJte0aNwCG6AJ4CA3IgC+yTNANUqoABKxoNCQBV5SlUVxF3AFVZNkh0bjZlFWiAH1A2D1AAXnlRCmp3AH5ggSjo0DiE5Pls3JUBIWdXIO881XVNbV19UCNTCxVraxQMHHxCSDEAQRISA2NPEINuEbGJr0qXN0nFKLUNLXjmwxNzK2Q0LDwCUFwAExp0PGx5kK5QD0rEn3qNwhoLbpBQYXsqFGGo3GbAA2gBGAC6ZWiADo-AE2KR0rQGDJBHU4f4aGxzpdru1EEA

Comment: Thank you very much. Hmm, that's what I'd like Flow to infer. Inside the function passed to `.pipe()`, I'd like to use a typed argument. I think it's possible just like Java Stream API does but I really don't know how.

Comment: Not sure, but I suspect that you dislike the verbosity of code that uses my proposed API. If you're looking to define the pipe's function inline, then consider https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQjIFcB2BjALgS1uqAA4BOsAtrgM4CmAcquQEY0kAUNAXKOoyyQEpuABTKVaAHl7NWAPlABvRKFAka2VCUJte0aNwCG6AJ4CA3IgC+yTNANUqoABKxoNCQBV5SlUVxF3AFVZNkh0bjZlFWiAH1A2D1AAXnlRCmp3AH5ggSjo0DiE5Pls3JUBIWdXIO881XVNbV19UCNTCxVraxQMHHxCSDEAQRISA2NPEINuEbGJr0qXN0nFKLUNLXjmwxNzK2QQUGF7KhRh0fG2AG0ARgBdMuiAOj8AtlJ02gYZQTqX-xobCBNGKoBolR0fFYoOk-Aqe0Qh2ODjOFFml1uDz+r0BH3E9Chv3y-zeaCweAIoEmHG4HkqiQU9Q2hBoZlAlj2QA

Comment: Great example. Yeah, but the both inline functions are ones with types. I still think the argument `e` can be inferred to be a `number`, because the previous function returns `Promise<number>`. I'm expecting it's possible in Flow.